# Unable to downgrade Node.js using nvm on Windows

Tags: node.js, nvm

I'm trying to downgrade Node's version via `nvm` on Windows 10, but I can't get it working:

> C:\projects>nvm use 16.13.2 all
> Now using node v16.13.2 (64-bit)

> C:\projects>node -v
> v17.4.0

(I `nvm install` and `nvm use` 16.13.2 on both 32 and 64bit; also tried to restart the command prompt, but always showing v17.4.0)

Comment: What does `where node` print?

Comment: @tkausl "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"

Comment: I might be wrong (not using NVM) but I assume thats not NVM's node instance. Did you install a nodejs instance manually, i.e. not through NVM? You might need to uninstall it.

Comment: @tkausl ty! that did the trick. I uninstalled the Windows app, re-installed through nvm, and now `node -v` shows v16.13.2 as I wanted. Please write an answer and I'll accept it straight away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your output of `where node`

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
```

You have another manually installed node version on your system. Since both, the manually installed node as well as the version provided by NVM have their locations in your `PATH` environment variable, the one which happens to come first in `PATH` wins (which in your case was the manually installed one) and the other one looses and won't be accessible (without using the full path).

So to fix it, uninstall node and use NVM to handle all node installations.